# How much can I heat a spring before it changes characteristics?

Tags: materials

I painted some “spring-tempered steel” stock with exhaust clear paint. The paint needs to be baked on. How much can I heat the springs till it becomes a problem?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Your comment sounds like the basis for an excellent answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant I used the paint up to 500F. Can I go to 300? 350?

Answer (score 1):

Baking at 500 F can easily lead to a phenomenon known as tempered martensite embrittlement (TME). Based on the number of papers I've seen that advance different theories about how this comes about, the causes seem to be poorly understood (or at least were until fairly recently, anyway).

The exact temperature at which you're likely to encounter TME varies depending on the alloy of the steel involved. One theory about how it comes about involves impurities such as silicon migrating to the grain boundaries, so changing the amount of those impurities seems to have a significant effect on the effect--both the temperature at which it's seen, and the degree to which the steel's toughness is lost from the treatment.

For example, here's the result of a test on 4340 steel.

[image]

As we can see, the loss of toughness is only *fairly* minor. But here's a test with 300-M steel, which is quite similar to 4340 except in terms of silicon content:

[image]

In this case, the embrittlement doesn't happen until a higher temperature--but when it happens, it's much more serious--toughness is reduced much more severely.

We'd probably need considerably more information about the precise steel alloy you're using to guess at a temperature at which it's safe to bake your coating without affecting the steel's tempering. Lacking that, you could do some tests with scraps of the same steel, if you have any, and (less likely) have the right equipment to test it with. I suppose if I had to take a guess, 300F is probably pretty safe for most kinds of steel. While there may be some exceptions, I believe alloys that undergo TME at lower temperatures *generally* also show less severe effects from it, so even if the steel you have shows TME at 300F (about 150C) chances are pretty good the effect will be quite mild anyway.
That said, a little testing beats even a good guess--and a guess without knowledge of the alloy you're using won't be the best.

#### Reference

[Mechanisms of Tempered Martensite
Embrittlement in Low Alloy Steels](https://www2.lbl.gov/ritchie/Library/PDF/1978_Horn_MetTransA_MechanismsOfTemperedMartensite.pdf)